# Showing that the real and imaginary part of a holomorphic function are $\mathrm{C}^{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a fairly easy question. Let me first describe the setting:

Let $f$ be defined on a domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Define the two functions

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{u}(x,y) = \Re(f(x+iy))\\
\widetilde{v}(x,y) = \Im(f(x+iy))
\end{equation}

so that of course

\begin{equation}
f(x+iy) = \widetilde{u}(x,y)+i\widetilde{v}(x,y).
\end{equation}

Let

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\Omega} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x+iy \in \Omega \}.
\end{equation}

Two facts are in order:

1. $f \in \mathrm{Hol}(\Omega)$ if and only if $\widetilde{u}$ and $\widetilde{v}$ are differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations in $\widetilde{\Omega}$;
2. if $f \in \mathrm{Hol}(\Omega)$, then $f$ is analytic in $\Omega$. In particular, $f \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

From these facts I want to prove that if $f \in \mathrm{Hol}(\Omega)$, then $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v} \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\widetilde{\Omega})$.

The way I see it:

Using the C-R equations, we can write

\begin{equation}
f’(x+iy) = \frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial x}(x,y) -i \frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial \widetilde{v}}{\partial y}(x,y) +i \frac{\partial \widetilde{v}}{\partial x}(x,y).
\end{equation}

Using (1), knowing by (2) that $f’$ is holomorphic, we see that $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}$ have differentiable (hence continuous) first partial derivatives, therefore they’re $\mathrm{C}^{1}(\widetilde{\Omega})$.

Iterating using the formula above, we see that $f^{(n)}$ can be written in $2^{n}$ different ways in which all the $n$-th partial derivatives of $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}$ figure, the mixed derivatives figuring with all their possible permutations. To clarify what I mean let me write down the case $n=2$, using a slimmer notation:

\begin{equation}
f’’ = \widetilde{u}_{xx} -i \widetilde{u}_{xy} = - \widetilde{u}_{yy} -i \widetilde{u}_{yx} = \widetilde{v}_{yx} -i \widetilde{v}_{yy} = \widetilde{v}_{xy} +i \widetilde{v}_{xx}.
\end{equation}

So, again by (1) and (2), at the $n$-th step of iteration we can conclude that $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v} \in \mathrm{C}^{n-1}(\widetilde{\Omega})$. Therefore, $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v} \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\widetilde{\Omega})$.

Now, my question: I’m just looking for alternative/cleaner ways to get this result. Thanks to all of you who will take their time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f = u + \sqrt{-1}v$ is holomorphic. Then the CR equations can be used to show that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic, i.e., $u_{xx} + u_{yy} =0$ and $v_{xx} + v_{yy}=0$ (this is a good undergraduate exercise). Then use elliptic regularity theory to assert that harmonic functions are smooth.

Does this help?

Comment: (+1) This is absolutely the heart of the matter.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not familiar with elliptic regularity theory. I know that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic and that harmonic functions are smooth, but the proofs that I’ve seen of the latter statement rely on the fact that a harmonic function locally admits a harmonic conjugate, so that I already need to know that $f \in \mathrm{Hol}(\Omega)$ implies $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v} \in \mathrm{C}^{\infty}(\widetilde{\Omega})$. I guess that what you suggest is the exactly opposite perspective. I will try to keep this in mind and maybe come back to this answer in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you! Funnily enough, I remember as an undergraduate wanting so badly to be the person who could correctly use the expression "by elliptic regularity theory" -- it definitely is central :)

Comment: @Federico I would encourage you to spend more time thinking about this problem. I will provide some alternative proofs later (perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f = u + \sqrt{-1} v$ for some $C^1$-functions $u,v : \tilde{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$. Writing $f$ as a sum of convergent power series, we have $$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k (z-w)^k,$$ where $c_k = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial z^k}$ and $w$ is some fixed point in $\tilde{\Omega}$. Note that we are appealing to the Cauchy integral formula here in order to write $f$ as the above series. (You should read the proof of this thoroughly - I would suggest Alexander Isaev's book *Twenty-One Lectures on Complex Analysis.*)

If you believe the above series representation (with the coefficients given as above) then we see that $\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial z^k}$ is defined for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Do you then believe that the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are so defined for all orders? (If not: Write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts).

*Warning:* I rushed this.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and answer. Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but I think that what you suggest here is the way I approached the problem in the body of the question. I had a full course in Complex Analysis so I’m well acquainted with these concepts. In fact what I’m looking for are alternative ways of getting this result. Elliptic regularity theory sounds great, but I will need a little bit of time to get there!

Comment: @Federico Take a look at Chapter 2 of Gilbarg and Trudinger :)

Comment: I will! Thank you for the advice :)